# Moving equations and aligns into outer margin

Tags: floats, positioning, koma-script, double-sided

I have rather narrow text width, so sometimes I have to move floats to the *outer* margin.  In case of drawings and tables I use command `\widefloat` defined below

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\widefloat}[1]{%
\ifthispageodd{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{#1}}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{table}[h]
\widefloat{\begin{tabular}{lll}
really really really really really & large large large large large & table table table table table \\
really really really really really & large large large large large & table table table table table \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\[
\frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y}\\
\]

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{table}[h]
\widefloat{\begin{tabular}{lll}
really really really really really & large large large large large & table table table table table \\
really really really really really & large large large large large & table table table table table \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\[
\frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y}\\
\]

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

However, when I try to apply it to `\equation`, I get errors and equation is transformed into inline-type of equation.

Is there any way to create a similar command for equations?

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs Better? :-)

Comment: Yes, much better :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same method; but it would be much preferable to split long equations with the help of `amsmath` environments (`split` for aligning pieces, `multline` for the non aligned case).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\wideeq}[1]{%
  \ifthispageodd
    {\makebox[\textwidth][l]{$\displaystyle#1$}}
    {\makebox[\textwidth][r]{$\displaystyle#1$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\[
\wideeq{%
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y}
}
\]
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\lipsum*[1]
\[
\wideeq{%
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y}
}
\]
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you should never leave a blank line before a displayed equation. This is why I used `\lipsum*` before the equation (it doesn't end the paragraph).

Using `\\` inside `\[...\]` is meaningless.

Comment: The designer specified textwidth of only 120 mm and margin of 55mm, so it makes sense pushing wide equations, pictures and tables into margin, like in Tufte style.  Wouldn't you agree?  Unfortunately, your method isn't working with `\align`.  Is something like that possible for `\align` too?

Comment: @Pygmalion With equation numbers? No way.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant `align*`, no equation numbers.

Comment: @Pygmalion Use `aligned` inside `\wideeq`

Comment: `aligned` within `equation` using the method above.  Of course, stupid me. *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use KOMA-Script's environment `addmargin*` to define an environment that additionally uses the margin note column in the outer margin. Such an environment can be used as container for tables, figures, equations etc.:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}% illustrate the text area, margin note column etc.

\newenvironment{wide}{%
  \begin{addmargin*}[0pt]{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
}{%
  \end{addmargin*}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{wide}
  \[
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y}
  \]
\end{wide}
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{wide}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
      really really really really really & large large large large large & table table table table table \\
      really really really really really & large large large large large & table table table table table \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{wide}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\lipsum*[1]
\begin{wide}
  \[
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y} = 
  \frac{x}{y} = \frac{x}{y}
  \]
\end{wide}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution.  Still one question.  The difference between your and egreg's solution is that egreg's solution "aligns" wide equation/table toward the internal margin, thus taking as little outer marginal space as possible.  In your case, wide equation/table is centred within body text + marginal space.  Is it possible to modify your solution so it works like egreg's?

Comment: For equations this wouldn't be easy, because you would need an equation environment, that align equations left, and an equation environment, that align equations right. For tables etc. this would be easy using `\ifthispagewasodd\raggedright\else\raggedleft\fi`.